# laravel 5.4 blank page issue

Tags: php, laravel-5, routes, laravel-5.4

I have configured Laravel 5.4 on the ubuntu server.
I successfully setup admin panel yesterday, then I made on more panel with name staff and setup it successfully.
But unfortunately "Admin panel" stopped working.

in **.env** file

```
APP_DEBUG=true
```

in **app.php** file

```
 'debug' => env('APP_DEBUG', true),
```

It does not display any errors. In logs, I can see this only:

> 0 [internal function]: App\Http\Controllers\Admin\SessionsController->store()
>
> 1 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Controller.php(55):
>   call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
>
> 2 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php(44):
>   Illuminate\Routing\Controller->callAction('store', Array)
>
> 3 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(203):
>   Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route),
>   Object(App\Http\Controllers\Admin\SessionsController), 'store')
>
> 4 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(160):
>   Illuminate\Routing\Route->runController()
>
> 5 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(572):
>   Illuminate\Routing\Route->run()
>
> 6 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(30):
>   Illuminate\Routing\Router->Illuminate\Routing{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
>
> 44 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(151):
>   Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
>
> 45 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(116):
>   Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
>
> 46 /var/www/html/public/index.php(54): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))

If I print `{{ Auth::User()->name }}` it is not printing anything in the blade file.

if I echo Auth::User()->id; in `SessionsController` then I can get the data, but in blade file, it is not working

**SessionsController.php**

```
public function store()
    {
        if(!auth()->attempt(request(['email','password'])))
        {
            Request()->session()->flash('error_msg', 'Please check your credentials and try again.');
            return back()->withErrors([
                'message' => 'Please check your credentials and try again.'
            ]);
        }

        return redirect()->home();
    }
```

In page source, it is displaying like this: http://prntscr.com/h1bc32

What can be the issue?

Comment: In the logs, the first few lines are more important than the last ones. Because the error message is actually there in the first line. Please post the first lines so we can help :)

Comment: @semihcosu see my edited question!

Comment: @semihcosu if i echo `Auth::User()->id;`  in `SessionsController` then i can get the data, but in blade file it is not working

Comment: Show this method please: `App\Http\Controllers\Admin\SessionsController->store()`

Comment: @Jackowski added.in that controller i can echo the id.

Comment: there's no such thing as a `Request()` it's either `request()` or `Request::`

Comment: @apokryfos where?

Comment: `Request()->session()->flash('error_msg', 'Please check your credentials and try again.');`

Comment: @apokryfos I tried that in 5.4, it works as `Request()` anyway :|

Comment: In page source, it is displaying like this: http://prntscr.com/h1bc32